# control panel shortcut in start menu is missing

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I do not know what did I do, but I cannot see the control panel shortcut in windows 7 start menu. How do I put it back.
The shortcut that comes with the computer, games, documents, device and printers shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click on the Start Orb
2. Select `Properties`
3. Click `Customise`
4. Ensure `Control Panel` is set to `Display as a link` or `Display as a menu`
5. Click `OK`
6. Click `OK`

[image]

Comment: @Shevek, yep, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start, in the search menu type "cmd".
2. After the results show area, right-click cmd or cmd.exe
3. Next right click on Run as administrator.
4. In the Command prompt, enter the appropriate password of the administrator account, if prompted, click Continue.
5. At the Command prompt, type `Sfc / scannow` and then press ENTER.

This post will be a bit time consuming, the result is indicated by percent, windows will repair corrupted files or missing files.
If information from the installation CD is required, insert the Windows Installer CD.